# Looking for Stellar Bifrost developers for setting up BiFrost properly

Tags: bifrost

for 2 wks we are experiencing difficulties with setting up BiFrost. We followed the instructions carefully but no one of our team were able to get it running. For no reason the BiFrost servers stopped running on our Digital Ocean server multiple times. Even re-installed Bifrost servers on our Digital Ocean but still no luck. We have no idea what caused the problems.

We searched on Stellar.org, Youtube and many more for BiFrost tutorials and solutions but to no avail.

Comment: Can you share the Bifrost logs?

Comment: Hello Bartek, unfortunately I've destroyed the BiFrost server on our Digital Ocean server after we saw multiple timeouts on our logs; at the same time we could see that the BiFrost server was switched off spontaneaously. See screenshot: http://picresize.com/popup.html?images/rsz_sct1.jpg

Comment: It works for a few moments (- minutes-hour) and suddenly BiFrost stops working, displaying the time-out errors. Removing, destroying and adding new BiFrost install does the same thing.

Comment: It seems that DigitalOcean destroys the droplets with Bifrost. This isn't really related to Bifrost app itself from what I can tell.

Comment: @Bartek. That was not the case: we've destroyed the BiFrost server. There were (probably) two things happening: a huge timeout of BiFrost, completely unresponsive like it was stuck in a loop. The other thing was that BiFrost spontaneaously quit its job. After that happened we destroyed BiFrost and re-installed it again. And i didn't work out because the same problems keep repeating again. So it was not Digital Ocean who destroyed BiFrost; we did that.

Comment: The timeouts you mention can be connected with firewall configuration and many other things. Really hard to tell anything without seeing the logs.

Comment: And you know a few weeks ago we installed BiFrost on one of our own (non-Digital Ocean) Linux servers and we also had the same timeout problems. Conclusion: I don;t think it's related to firewall or Digital oCean or our servers.

Comment: Hey Bartek, We've been working for almost 3 wks on BiFrost to make it work. I'll pay if you can make BiFrost working on our servers. Otherwise we've wasted so much time that it would be better to drop BiFrost as a flawed application and Stellar as the ICO platform and move on to Ethereum. There's no other option I guess. Or at least provide us a good step-by-step (video) tutorial so we can see what went wrong. Another option is to recommend us a good developer who've worked with BiFrost and ICO's/

Comment: Bifrost has been deployed by multiple organizations in the past and this is the first time I hear about timeouts. As I said above, hard to say anything without seeing the logs. If you have any specific problem with Bifrost please ask here, if you need a developer check Stellar forums or slack (slack.stellar.org).

Comment: Hey Bartek, over the weeks my team and developers we're "shopping" on Reddit, Stellar, Slack with the same problem and even you referred us to Stackexchange and now you're going to refer us back to other sites. You see this is the problem. I begin to understand that you're not willing to help us, even when we offer you (as BiFrost developer) money. You know I've wasted so much time on nonsenses like this that I'm going to dump BiFrost and Stellar as the ICO platform. Have a good day.

Comment: I offered you help for free here :). In any kind of software if you experience problems you are asked to share your logs. As I said nothing I can do without seeing the logs. Even if you want to dump Stellar (which obviously I think is a bad idea) remember that you'd need to find or build Bifrost-like server for the other blockchain if you want to receive payments in BTC/ETH and I can tell you it will take much more time than fixing (probably a small issue) you are experiencing with Bifrost.

Comment: Hey Bartek, like I said before we installed our own BiFrost servers on Digital Ocean, our own servers and even Azure. Everytime it crashed suddenly and destroyed everything, re-installed again, got crashed again, destroyed again. And yes we don't have the logs anymore, but maybe the long timeouts will point you into the right direction....

Answer (score 1):

Well, my previous post got deleted because of personal info I guess, so I edit it to this:

You could ask for your demand in slack (https://slack.stellar.org/) in the jobs channel #jobs

Answer (score 0):

I can feel your pain.

Stellar Bifrost looks good on paper but it will never get mass adaption because it's a small community and the support is pretty lame.
Only a handful companies managed to get BiFrost working and they won't share how they did it. You see that's the problem.

I've also been struggling with BiForst for a couple of weeks and decided to switch to Ethereum. Their community is very big and with good support. On YouTube you can find tons of video-tutorials for setting up ERC-20 Ethereum and complicated time-locked contracts. Is there a videotutorial of BiFrost on YouTube? No...vAs I've wasted so much time with BiFrost I've decided to hire an Ethereum developer....Within one day (!) I've found one who even developed customized time locked contracts the same day (!). Try that in this community. I see you've been communicating here a couple of days. Have you found a developer? No? Waste no more time just switch!

Again, Stellar BiFrost looks good on paper but their support should be way better in order to get mass adaption. Unfortunately it won't change unless this community begins to realize that things have to change right away. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This article pretty much explains why you should **not** switch to Ethereum (long article but worth a read):

https://blog.stellarx.com/the-great-filter-why-you-shouldnt-ico-on-ethereum/amp/?__twitter_impression=true

The problem in not getting help is mostly caused by not providing enough sources ...

stackexchange also is not meant to search developers. To search developers go to slack and join jobs channel. Ask there for a developer.

You could also ask for help in the dev channel if help is specific. Otherwise stackexchange should be used so that others who will encounter the same problem will find it here.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the tip but we've also posted questions and requests on Slack a couple of weeks ago but there was really nobody who replied. I checked others posting and all had the same experience. There was no one from staff who replied the requests or could help me or other users.

No real activity. This way Stellar will never reach mass adoption.